# activerecord shovel operator <<

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

From inside edit action in the contacts controller have ...

```
@programs << @contact.program
```

Which produces the following error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `<<' for Program::ActiveRecord_Relation
```

Contacts Model:

```
belongs_to :program
```

Program Model:

```
has_many :contacts
validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

@programs.class
Program::ActiveRecord_Relation

@contact.program.class
Program(id: integer, name: string, active: boolean, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Question: Why does this operation fail?  Why can't the record get added to the record collection.  What is preventing the collection(ActiveRecord_Relation) from adding the record?

Comment: I need to add the contact's program to program, that's all

Comment: `Program` does not `has_many :programs`. If you want to simply persist “contact’s program”, just call `.save` on it.

Answer (score 1):

You're contradicting yourself here:

`Program has_many contacts` vs `Programs << Contact.program`

If you're trying to add a `Contact` to a particular program, you would be looking at adding the contact:

```
program.contacts << contact
```

And if you're trying to set the program for the contact:

```
contact.program = program
```

What does not make sense, however, is to try to add something to “programs”, which isn't a relationship. Nothing in this system as you've defined it `has_many :programs`, so `@programs.<<` cannot possibly act on a relationship.

Comment: programs << contact.program
#<NameError: undefined local variable or method `programs' for #<ContactsController:0x007fc0b4362de8>

Comment: program << contact.program

Comment: #<NameError: undefined local variable or method `program' for #<ContactsController:0x007fc0b4362de8>

Comment: SORRY, ACTUALLY THIS ISN'T WORKING

Comment: @user6337901 Read more closely? Your comments are at odds with what I wrote. Also, you have to actually know Ruby to write it. It isn't magic. Variables don't just suddenly appear, you have to define them.

Answer (score 1):

You're receiving this error because the `ActiveRecord::Relation` class is only a collection of results returned by an `ActiveRecord` query. You probably got it by running `Program.where` or a similar query. It is not an `ActiveRecord::Association` and therefore you cannot add more records to it.

You must instead use the association returned by the parent object.

Here's an example of what you're doing, vs what you should be doing:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :programs
end

class Program < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end

new_program = Program.new

# What you're attempting.
programs_where = Program.where(user_id: User.first) # Class is Program::ActiveRecord_Relation
programs_where << new_program # Throws Error b/c << is not available on ActiveRecord::Relation objects.

# What you should be attempting.
user = User.first
programs_assoc = user.programs # Returns Programs::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy
programs_assoc << new_program # Returns Correctly
```

Note: It's not clear how `@programs` is defined. Is this answer does not work for you then please provide the complete controller code, as well as the other model you're using.